# Check if J# framework installed

Tags: vb.net, frameworks, j#

I have a VB.NET 2008 (FW 3.5) app with J# 2.0 as a prerequisite.
For some problems I have to check during runtime if this framework is installed.
How can I do?

Thanks

Alessio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the post "[What registry keys indicate that J# is installed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualjsharpgeneral/thread/89dd85ba-eed4-4d83-9c77-c1863c0abf6d)" helpful.